# Check What field are blank/untouched in wizard based form

Tags: angularjs

I have a multi step wizard based form in which there are 8 pages which i am loading on some condition using ng-include.

Also, at last step there is a confirmation which shows all the fields and its value entered by User and "Submit" is only activated if all the validations passes successfully.

I want to show error messages at last step for those fields which are left blank/untouched or have some error, so that user can see why submit is not activated.

for example:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label magenta" for="purposeDescription">What is your purpose for this site?</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="12" name="purposeDescription" ng-model="request.purpose" id="purposeDescription"  required=""></textarea>
</div>
```

if user has not filled in some value then i need to show message at last step.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? You can define the `form` in the overall wizard scope. On the last page you can check if the form is valid `form.$valid` or if there are some validation errors `form.$error`.

Also check https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms for form validation.

Comment: $valid and $dirty are your friends